# Update Multiple PivotTables in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

I have 3 sheets where the first sheet contain the data, second is the pivot table while the third sheet is the pivot chart generate from the pivot table. I want to create a VBA update button whereby it will update both the pivot table and pivot chart once there is changes in the data source.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
Sub Update_Pivot()

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    
    lr = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A3:AR" & lr)
    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
             pt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
                PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rng)
    Next pt
    Next ws
      
End Sub
```

However, I receive an error whereby the error was in the `pt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rng)` saying that Run-time error '5'.

Does my coding correct? How can I solve this error?

Comment: It works for me, so probably you have a range /data problem , not a coding problem. Check your Range, put a watch on rng and make sure it matches you source table (headers and data)

Comment: If you are looping through sheets and on each sheet, looping through pivots, you should be all set. What, exactly, is not working?

Comment: @wrbp my pivot table was in data model. is it because of that?

Comment: @izzatfi, probable, what is the source of your data model?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looping through sheets and on each sheet, looping through pivots, you should be pretty close.

After this:

```
For Each pt
```

use this code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'This line disable the on screen update for better performance, the blink you see, you could delete both lanes but it will run slower
Dim myChart As ChartObject
For Each myChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    myChart.Chart.Refresh
Next myChart
Application.ScreenUpdating = True'This line reenable the on screen update for better performance, the blink you see, you could delete both lanes but it will run slower
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Sub Update()

For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            For Each Pivot In Sheet.PivotTables
                Pivot.RefreshTable
                Pivot.Update
            Next
            Dim myChart As ChartObject
            For Each myChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
                myChart.Chart.Refresh
            Next myChart
Next
For Each Chart In ThisWorkbook.Charts ' if chart is not part of a sheet, but on its own 
            Chart.Refresh
        Next
End Sub
```